# Relationship between SABR and Heston

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston, sabr

What is the relationship between SABR parameters $\sigma, \alpha, \beta, \rho$ and heston parameters $\nu, \kappa, \theta, \xi, \rho$?

How do they influence the smile; skewness, kurtosis, etc? And how are they related to one another, i.e., if I calibrate Heston to SABR for some fixed SABR-parameters, how will the estimated Heston parameters depend on the fixed SABR parameters?

Is there some good literature on the relationship between these two?

Comment: Add the equations for both stochastic processes to your question please.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the two models is described in details in [Implied Volatility Formulas for Heston Models](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/wilm.10723) by Hagan et al.
In particular an expansion of the implied volatility under the Heston model that matches the one of a SABR model is described. It gives an explicit correspondence between the parameters of each model.